# How to access Unity settings from Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I've a published game in Unity. Now I want to release an update with Java/Android instead.

The problem is that I want to import the existing game settings. In [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) is written:

> On Android data is stored (persisted) on the device. The data is saved
>   in SharedPreferences. C#/JavaScript, Android Java and Native code can
>   all access the PlayerPrefs data. The PlayerPrefs data is physically
>   stored in /data/data/pkg-name/shared_prefs/pkg-name.xml.

The question is that Unity saves data in which key? I tried:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String, ?> allEntries = sharedPreferences.getAll(); // it returns nothing
```

also I tried to access that file:

```
File file = new File("/data/data/com.mycompany.app/shared_prefs/com.mycompany.app.xml");
boolean exists = file.exists(); // it doesn't exist
```

How to access Unity settings from Java/Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can take a look at the stored Shared Preferences for yourself.

1. Open Android Studio and plug in a device with your installed game
2. Find the tab at the bottom right of AS labelled "Device File Explorer"
3. In the resulting folder structure navigate to `data/data/your_package_name/shared_prefs`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was saved in a file like: `/data/data/com.mycompany.app/shared_prefs/com.mycompany.app.v2.playerprefs.xml` .. So to be safe it's better to list all the files in that directory.